# Input to console application in C#

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, dll, console-application

I created a dll file for my matlab program. I integrated it into C# console application now I have to call this console application from php. The user selects an image whose imagepath should be passed as input in the C# console application.

I checked the console application my defining an image path and it works fine how can I program it to accept input from php aplication so that I can call exec(exepath imgpath)in php. I have to pass the image path to the matlab dll file too. My Console application is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using shoesddl;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;


namespace shoes_describe
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            shoesddl.shoes_describe obj = new shoesddl.shoes_describe();

            MWArray img= "C:/Users/adithi.a/Desktop/dressimages/T1k5aHXjNqXXc4MOI3_050416.jpg";
            obj.shoes(img);
        }
    }    
}
```

I need the imgpath i.e img in the above program from php. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [Command Line Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Your method is accepting parameters in `string[] args`. You can pass the image path alongwith the `exe` name, from your PHP code.

```
> exepath imgpath
```

That `imagepath` would available at `args[0]`

Comment: But the obj.shoes expects a MWArray so I have to pass obj.shoes(MWArray) is this possible?

Comment: @user1583647, you will pass the `imagepath` based on that you need to create `MWArray` in your code. From your current code it appears you are trying to assing simple string to `MWArray`, you can do `MWArray = args[0]`